# How to change data in dynamically added Android Views at runtime

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-view, firebase

I have and `Android` app which adds `TableViews,` `TableRows` and `TextViews` dynamically at run time according to data found in a `Firebase` repository. More specifically, a `TableView` is added for each "Poll" found in the repo to the static `LinearLayout`, for each "Election" found in the Poll a `TableRow` is added to that `Tablelayout`, and for each "Nominee" in the Election a `TableRow` containing two `TextViews` for data is added to the `TableLayout` as well. So potentially I could have multiple tables added at runtime, each containing rows for multiple elections, and each election having multiple data rows for nominees. Here's my static layout for good measure....

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ScrollView android:layout_height="android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:orientation="vertical"> 
</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

..and here's a representation of my `Firebase` repo...

```
-POLLS
    NUMPOLLS - 5
    (pollskey) - NAME - Poll1
            NUMELECTIONS - 2
            ELECTIONS 
                (electionskey) - NAME - Election1
                        NUMNOMINATIONS - 2
                        NUMVOTERS - 2
                        NUMBERTOELECT - 1
                        VOTERS - (votesrkey) - NAME - Charles
                                         NUMBER - (678) 333-4444
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
                                 (voterskey) - ...
                        NOMINATIONS - (nominationskey) - NAME - Richard Nixon
                                              NUMBEROFVOTES - 2
                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
                                      (nominationskey) - ...
            .
            .
            .
            (electionskey) - ...
     .
     .
     .
     (pollskey) - ...
```

So my question really has two threads. The first is Android oriented...

1. What's the best way to iterate through `Android` views added dynamically to change `TextView` data when data in the repo changes, it being the case that I have no idea how many such `TableView`, or `TableRows` there will be at compile time?

Right now I'm doing something like this, but it's very slow going I feel like there has to be a better way...

```
private void appendCandidatesAndVotes(DataSnapshot election, TableLayout tbl) {
        Random randGen = new Random();
        DataSnapshot nominees = election.child("Nominations");
        for (DataSnapshot nominee : nominees.getChildren()) {

            // Create row for candidate name and number of votes
            TableRow rowNameAndVotes = new TableRow(this);
            // Generating a random row ID here allows us to pass this to 
            // the valueEventListener and quickly locate this row in 
            // the case of a data change (someone has cast a vote) so we 
            // can update
            int uniqueRowId = randGen.nextInt(1000);
            rowNameAndVotes.setId(uniqueRowId);
            rowNameAndVotes.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            rowNameAndVotes.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams (
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // Create candidate name view
            TextView viewCandidateName = new TextView(this);
            viewCandidateName.setId(2);
            viewCandidateName.setText(nominee.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
            viewCandidateName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewCandidateName.setPadding(5,  5,  5, 5);
            rowNameAndVotes.addView(viewCandidateName);

            // Create number of votes view
            TextView viewNumVotes = new TextView(this);
            viewNumVotes.setId(3);
            viewNumVotes.setText(nominee.child("NumberOfVotes").getValue(String.class));
            viewNumVotes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            viewNumVotes.setPadding(3,  5,  5,  5);
            rowNameAndVotes.addView(viewNumVotes);

            // Add row to table
            tbl.addView(rowNameAndVotes);

            // Lets get a Firebase reference for this nominee and
            // attach a listener to alert us to all future changes of
            // the values therein, so we can update vote counts dynamically
            Firebase nomineeRef = nominee.getRef();
            nomineeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot nomineeSnapshot) {

                    String nomineeName = nomineeSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
                    int layoutChildCount = layout.getChildCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < layoutChildCount; i++) {
                        View layoutChildView = layout.getChildAt(i);
                        // If its a Table, loop through all row
                        if (layoutChildView instanceof TableLayout) {
                            TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)layoutChildView;
                            int tableChildCount = tbl.getChildCount();
                            for (int j = 0; j < tableChildCount; j++) {
                                View tblChildView = tbl.getChildAt(i);
                                if (tblChildView instanceof TableRow) {
                                    TableRow row = (TableRow)tblChildView;
                                    int rowChildren = row.getChildCount();
                                    for (int k = 0; k < rowChildren; k++) {
                                        TextView tv = (TextView)(row.getChildAt(k));
                                        String rowCandidateName = tv.getText().toString();
                                        if (rowCandidateName) ...
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I *think* the way this is layed out, the only layout I can directly refer to is the base `LinearLayout`. I can give all `TableRows` unique ids with `setId()`, but as far as I know I can't pass any data to the `ValueEventListener`, nor can I refer to any variables in the enclosing scope (I hope I'm wrong about this, it would make things way easier). I know I can refer to static final variables inside the `ValueEventListener`, but I don't see how this will help me since I don't know how many Tables or Rows I'll be dealing with at runtime.

So, in short, how can I link a particular call to the `ValueEventListener` with the `TableRow` it's data is associated with?

Now for question 2, which is a bit more `Firebase` specific....

1. It seems like `ValueEventListener` is called once when the activity is loaded, and then again for any changes to the underlying data. But I only want it called for changes to underlying data, not on loading. Am I using the wrong EventListener? Or is there some way to avoid this behavior?

Comment: "So, in short, how can I link a particular call to the ValueEventListener with the TableRow it's data is associated with?" Maybe try subclassing ValueEventListener and add a field to store the data you need. Also, not sure exactly what Firebase is, but do you think CursorAdapters might apply to this situation?

Comment: Hmmm maybe, I'm looking at a tutorial now. Firebase is just a storage service that lets you store data and retrieve it on events like ValueEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Firebase specific question - this is by design. Firebase doesn't encourage distinguishing between initial data and data updates, since in a real-time scenario you can never really be "caught up" to the latest data.

If you don't want to retrieve all the data on startup, then I'd use queries and limits to restrict what data you can receive. For instance, if you only want to receive the latest 100 polls, you could do something like:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(url);
Query q = ref.limit(100);
q.addChildEventListener(...);
```

and the child event listener will be called once per poll. When a new poll is added it will be called again (and there will be a child-removed event for the oldest poll in the list of 100).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, yeah it did. Thanks Anant!